# Magento2: Check the payment tab is activated

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, payment-methods, tabs, checkbox

I have init js and corresponding template in ***checkout_index_index*** (after payment method).

In that template, I have added on checkout after the payment methods.

If I checked the checkbox, I have added a custom fee.

In page-load, I have checked the checkbox using the afterRender method.

But the order total is not reflected with the fee.

How to check the check-box when the payment method tab is activated.

Comment: Please share the source code what you are done with `afterrender` and how  you applying fee to cart.

Comment: In AfterRender, I have called ajax call for add fee and trigger total. It is done and the total call returns the correct value. But the total is not reflected in order summary block.